# How to eliminate duplicates from select query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, distinct

Before asking this question I searched using Google but I couldn't understand or maybe could not find a solution suitable for my situation.

So, I have one Table with 10 columns, I want to eliminate duplicates from **select** result. And in the result all columns should be presented which has unique userID's

```
+-----------------------------------+------+---------------------+------+
| name                              | yr   |   some Columns      |userID|
+-----------------------------------+------+---------------------+------+
| abc                               | 2000 |                     |   10 |
| jack                              | 2000 |                     |   11 |
| dadas                             | 2000 |                     |   12 |
| jack                              | 2004 | .............       |   11 |
| jack                              | 2000 | ...........         |   11 |
| nell                              | 2006 | .............       |   13 |
| ......                            | 2000 | .............       |   1  |
| .............                     | 2000 | .............       |   2  |
| again                             | 2000 | .............       |   3  |
| again                             | 2000 |                     |   3  |
| .......                           | 1973 | .............       |   2  |
| abc                               | 2000 |                     |   10 |
```

Comment: So for `userID` 11 what do you want the `name` and `yr` to display as?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Could you draw up what the result set you are looking for would look like?

Comment: I think you need to tighten up your definition of unique. Which row should be picked where userID = 2? The other fields have conflicting information. Which one is right?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you don't need to keep different yrs, just use DISTINCT ON (FIELD_NAME)

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (userID) userdID, name, yr FROM TABLE_NAME
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this one:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME GROUP BY userID
```

Comment: I dont know about PostgreSQL...  But SQL-Server will throw an error on this query.

Comment: Almost all dbms's will throw an error on this query, it's not valid SQL. Even MySQL will throw an error when a proper configuration is used.

Comment: @mu is too short . . Thanks for the edit.
@Frank Heikens . . I have tested this query in MySQL. It works. I haven't tested in PostgreSQL and SQL

Comment: The query is going to produce results in MySQL as far as working ... it will select distinct userIDs. Look at the rows where userID = 2. Which one will get picked?  One has year 1973 another 2000. Is this important? We do not know. This is why other servers throw an error. MySQL will pick one of the rows **arbitrarily**. The poster does not really say what distinct means so I suppose your query is pretty good in the fact that it keeps the ambiguity.

Answer (score 4):

For **PostgreSQL** as well as SQL Server 2005+, DB2 and later versions of Oracle (9+), you can use the windowing function ROW_NUMBER()

```
select *
from
(
select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by userID order by yr desc) rown
) X
where rown = 1
```

Comment: @a_h thanks for the note. Updated answer with emphasis on OP's RDBMS

Comment: @cyberwiki: you don't need the "latest" version of Oracle btw. The windowing functions are available since Version 8 :)

Comment: Nope. Oracle 8i came out around '97. That would have been the time when SQL Server 6 was current I think.

Comment: @a_h - I'm digging a hole for myself. TBH I only played with Oracle from v10 onwards :) thanks for your insights

Comment: @cyberwiki: you are welcome! I was more than delighted when the analytical functions (Oracle's name for them) made it into the standard and started appearing in other DBMS as well.

Comment: @cyberwiki: I had to re-check that and was proven wrong: It was Oracle 9 that introduced the analytical functions which was released 2001.

Comment: @a_h - I was not so daft after all! `A_H 2:1 C_K`

Answer (score 1):

An easy one would be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (userID) userdID, name, yr FROM TABLE_NAME
```